# How can i update just one key pair in a Secrets Manager secret?

Tags: terraform, aws-step-functions, aws-ssm

Does anyone know how to update only one key-pair in a SSM Secrets Manager secret using terraform or with the AWS Step Functions using service integrations?

I would like to avoid recreating the secret. So for example if my secrets manager secret was

```
{
   url: google.com,
   fname: jeff,
   lname: smith
}
```

I might want to update it to be:

```
{
   url: amazon.com,
   fname: jeff,
   lname: smith
}
```